# Facebook local currency error_code: 1383003

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, payment

While trying to test local currency payment I see this error on javascript pay dialog callback:

```
{"error_code":1383003,"error_message":"Account id missing. sender: 235265828 receiver: 0"}
```

In facebook dialog I see this:

```
Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction. Please try again.
```

og:product object is correct (tested by Facebook Object Debugger), payments enabled, company for payments registered and selected, realtime updates script also selected and working.

I have no any ideas what to do. I found only one similar question with solution to set company for payments. And I tried to test payment by different users with different roles (developer, testers, administrators). Also in facebook error list I saw meager description for error 1383003:

```
1383003 - PaymentFailure - Processor decline.
```

Comment: Could be something here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631428/facebook-local-currency-payment-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have a company setup. That will definitely cause this error, try adding a tax ID in the company and see if you still get this issue.